# Display the content of many to many fields in django template

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I want to know how it is possible to display many-to-many relations in the django template. I posted my views.py and my models.py. I tried to find the solution by myself but I didn't really understand how to solve the problem :/

**models.py**

```
class topic(models.Model):
        topic = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Thema')
        learningObjectivesTopic = models.ManyToManyField(learningObjective, verbose_name = "Lernziel")

class learningObjective(models.Model):
        learningObjectives = models.TextField(verbose_name = 'Lernziel')
```

**views.py**

```
@login_required(login_url='login')
def themen(request):
        return render(request, 'themen.html')

@login_required(login_url='login')
def create_themen(request):
        neueThemen=topic(topic=request.POST['thema'])
        neueThemen.save()
        neueThemen_Lernziel=learningObjective(learningObjectives=request.POST['Lernziel'])
        neueThemen_Lernziel.save()
        neueThemen.learningObjectivesTopic.add(neueThemen_Lernziel)
        return render(request, 'themen.html', {'thema': topic.objects.all(), 'lernziel': learningObjective.objects.all()})
```

and my unfinished **template** "themen.html"

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

<form action="{% url 'create_themen' %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
<br>Hallo Benutzer: {{ user.username }}</br>
<br>Thema: <textarea name="thema" rows="3" cols="45"></textarea></br>
<br>Lernziel: <textarea name="Lernziel" rows="3" cols="45"></textarea></br>
<input type="submit" value="Absenden" />

<br>Aktuelle Themen:</br>
</form>
{% for thema_ in thema %}
{{ thema_.topic }}<br/>
{{ thema_.
{% endfor %}


</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the `thema` object, if you want to display the many to many fields,

```
{% for topic in thema %}
    {{topic.topic}}
    {% for lo in topic.learningObjectivesTopic.all %}
        {{lo.learningObjectivesTopic}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: same thing.. not change in the way you access many to many. Please try it once before you think it doesnt work